# Configuring Ubuntu as internal network router

Tags: networking, virtualbox, internet, x11-forwarding

I am configuring an **internal network** using Virtual Box and 4 Virtual Machines. I have configured all the interfaces and messed a bit with **IP Forwarding** and **IP Masquerade** on Host which would be the **router**.

Router has **two ethernet interfaces**: one connected to HostC and the other connected with HostA and HostB.

What have I done wrong if **HostC** is able to ping to **Hosts A and B** but **Hosts A and B** can't ping to **HostC**. It should be the router configuration.

Answer (score 0):

In order to diagnose the problem here you should really add some more information to your post, I am adding this as an answer for clarity as there are a few commands to try to diagnose this and it would be hard to read in a comment. On your router please run these commands and report the output it will help to understand your network setup and configuration and identify the problem:

List interfaces:

```
ip link show
```

List interface forwarding state:

```
sysctl -a | grep forwarding
```

List interface addresses:

```
ip addr show
ip -6 addr show
```

List firewall rules:

```
iptables -L
ip6tables -L
```

List NAT rules:

```
iptables -t nat -L
ip6tables -t nat -L
```

Also please check that the router itself can reach all the hosts:

```
ping -c4 HostA
ping -c4 HostB
ping -c4 HostC
```

Where of course replace HostA/B/C with the hosts IP addresses, this is an important step since if there is an issue here then that needs to be resolved first before there is any point in trying to worry about routing between the subnets.

Comment: The next answer is irrelevant now.
I've just fixed it. Thanks to your comment I started thinking about firewall and I found out that HostC is on WinXP and there is default firewall enabled there. I turned it off and everything look fine.
Thank you so much.

Comment: I actually have another question. What should I change in router configuration so that it will enable routing from local hosts to the internet?
I have the third interface which is connected to the internet. I've got connection from HostR but not from other hosts. What can be the problem here?

Answer (score 0):

`ip link show`

Result:

`2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:90:2d:e5 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:d4:ac:c1 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff`

Everything looks fine.

`sysctl -a |grep forwarding`

Result:

`net.ipv4.conf.all.forwarding = 1
net.ipv4.conf.all.mc_forwarding = 0
net.ipv4.conf.default.forwarding = 1
net.ipv4.conf.default.mc_forwarding = 0
net.ipv4.conf.eth0.forwarding = 1
net.ipv4.conf.eth0.mc_forwarding = 0
net.ipv4.conf.eth1.forwarding = 1
net.ipv4.conf.eth1.mc_forwarding = 0
net.ipv4.conf.eth2.forwarding = 1
net.ipv4.conf.eth2.mc_forwarding = 0
net.ipv4.conf.lo.forwarding = 1
net.ipv4.conf.lo.mc_forwarding = 0
net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding = 0
net.ipv6.conf.all.mc_forwarding = 0
sysctl: reading key "net.ipv6.conf.all.stable_secret"
net.ipv6.conf.default.forwarding = 0
net.ipv6.conf.default.mc_forwarding = 0
sysctl: reading key "net.ipv6.conf.default.stable_secret"
net.ipv6.conf.eth0.forwarding = 0
net.ipv6.conf.eth0.mc_forwarding = 0
sysctl: reading key "net.ipv6.conf.eth0.stable_secret"
net.ipv6.conf.eth1.forwarding = 0
net.ipv6.conf.eth1.mc_forwarding = 0
sysctl: reading key "net.ipv6.conf.eth1.stable_secret"
net.ipv6.conf.eth2.forwarding = 0
net.ipv6.conf.eth2.mc_forwarding = 0
sysctl: reading key "net.ipv6.conf.eth2.stable_secret"
net.ipv6.conf.lo.forwarding = 0
net.ipv6.conf.lo.mc_forwarding = 0
sysctl: reading key "net.ipv6.conf.lo.stable_secret"`

Forwarding is enabled.

`ip addr show`

IP addresses are fine. Checked in Cisco Packet Tracer.

`ip -6 addr show`

ipv6 not configured.

`iptables -L`

Result:

`Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination`

`iptables -S`

Result:

`-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P FORWARD ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT`

Now default.

`Pinging`

HostR (router,10.0.0.1,172.16.0.1) pings to HostA, HostB, can't to HostC

HostA/HostB (10.0.0.5/.6) pings to HostA/B, HostR, can't to HostC

HostC (172.16.0.2) pings to all.

Thank you for your answer. Please tell me what you think about these results. I'm now trying to deal with it. I will report if any breakthrough happens.